# How to change header border color , text color and background color in QT?

Tags: qt

> In my application im using tablewidget thats works fine but not able to change border color and background color and text color of the table. I want the "white" border color ,"black" background color and "white" text color for entire table (include cells). I tried the code like,

```
//
tableWidget->item(0,0)->setBackgroundColor(Qt::black);
tableWidget->item(0,0)->setTextColor(Qt::white);
//the above 2 lines works fine , but how to set cell border color as white
QString styleSheet = "::section{" // "QHeaderView::section {""spacing: 10px;""background-color: green;""color:white;""border: 1px solid white;""margin: 1px;""text-align: right;""font-family: arial;" "font-size: 12px; }";
tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setStyleSheet(styleSheet);
```

> I tried the stylesheet also but that also not working.Guide me,

Comment: You have wrong stylesheet. What is "::section" selector? Did you read Qt documentation? You should set a stylesheet for table view, not diretly to header. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qheaderview

Comment: @saz : Thanks , for table header works fine , pls guide me to change the border color for all cells

Comment: As of now im using like , tableWidget->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section{background-color: black;color:white;border: 1px solid white;}"); its works well for background color , but how to set for cells border color

Comment: "the border color for all cells" - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html